# Can't install sublime text's package

Tags: macos, installation, package, editor, sublimetext

I'm going to download the sublime text and download the package
Package Control has been installed. by the way
Nothing comes out when I type Install Package
What should I do in this case?

I try reinstall sublime text to install sublime text's package

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution on sublime text forum.

> You should install the latest beta version manually: https://github.com/wbond/package_control/releases/tag/4.0.0-beta8 158

> Note that the downloaded file will need to be renamed, it needs to be Package Control.sublime-package (with a space) and not Package.Control.sublime-package as Github will distribute it.

Link to the source: https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/package-control-does-not-work-macos-sublime-4/68613/4
Credits to the author [aborel](https://forum.sublimetext.com/u/aborel)